# Issue Google Analytics Install Tracker for IOS

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to set up link with utm's to track app installs from Apple App Store. In iOS Campaign Tracking URL Builder is requirement to enter Google Analytics Property ID in UA-XXXX-Y format. In my account -> admin -> property setting there I can able to find 'property id' in google analytics, but it shows in different 9 digits format which is unacceptable in URL Builder. What shall I do?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#troubleshoot-enable

In above mentioned link they are asked to enable IOS tracking test but in new google analytics version I couldn't able to see those options,The documentation and actual analytics tool not matching

Please let me updated documentation link as well as clarify above mentioned query?

Comment: Your using GA4 not universal analytics, they cant be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Universal Analytics Property enabling advanced option when you create a new Google Analytics Property. In this case you can obtain the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X:

[image]

Anyway, tracking for apps with the Google Analytics SDK is deprecated (it is no longer possible to create a Universal Analytics Property for apps).

You must instead use Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started

Comment: Thanks for your information, We can track user events and screens in firebase analytics, please let me know how to track user installs using firebase analytics

Comment: Not possible in IOS , only android .
Go to AppConnect, you can use AppAnalytics campiagns to track AppUnit installed for IOS